# Cannot mount partition into old mount point

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, mountpoint

I have 2 disks (system and data) in my computer. 
The data HDD has two partitions, one for media and one for private data (encrypted with veracrypt). The mount points are: `/media/[myusername]/Media` for media, and `/media/veracrypt1` for my private data. So far so good.

The problem is, I replaced the the data HDD with a bigger one (same partitions), and now I cannot use my old mount point for the media partition. I can use `/media/[myusername]/Media1`, `/media/[myusername]/Media2` and so on, but not `/media/[myusername]/Media`.

When i mount it into `/media/[myusername]/Media`, it is empty. The private data partition (mounted with veracrypt) works fine.

Does anyone know why and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I  had this issue once but I'll be darned if I can remember how I fixed it .. have you tried to delete the Media folder and then make it again? of course I mean the`/media/[myusername]/Media` folder

Comment: yes, I deleted it, rebooted and tried again, but it doesn't work ....

Comment: are you mounting it through fstab or just manually mounting it? if mounting manually what is the error you get when you try to mount it to the mount point?

Comment: i tried both - no errors, it seems to be a permission problem (I can access it as root), but only with the `Media` folder . I created it manually, changed the permissions and still cannot access it as user. Every other folder (Media1,..) works with user permissions

Comment: man I wish my memory was better .. this was the exact problem I had .. I could mount it but it was root accessible only ... I was using fstab to mount it .. it was something with the settings of fstab that caused it but .. again I cant for the life of me remember what the setting was or how I fixed it :(

Comment: again .. how are you mounting it .. that may be helpful .. if its fstab what is the line you are using in fstab to mount it .. if you are manually mounting it what is the command you are using .. that may help jog my memory or help someone else who reads this and will see whats causing it

Comment: Manually: `sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb2 /media/[username]/Media`, 
or with fstab, the entry is: `/dev/disk/by-uuid/14D252A2D252883E /media/[username]/Media ntfs user,auto,defaults,x-gvfs-show 0 0` and then `mount -a`

Comment: ahh ok its NTFS .. here is my ntfs line `UUID=F858A91658A8D522                           /acronis  ntfs-3g  defaults  0    0` and I can access the files fine under my user login .. root is not necessary ... I think it's the user, in your fstab line but not sure about the manual mount one don't know what you can change for that .. I would try just defaults like mine and ntfs-3g .. and then `mount -a`

Comment: so the line I would try in your fstab would be `UUID=14D252A2D252883E /media/[username]/Media ntfs-3g defaults 0 0` and then `mount -a` and see if that works for you

Comment: still does not work and I already tried a lot of different parameters, I guess I have to use `/media/[username]/Media1` and change the paths .. its a really weired problem. Thanks for the help and if you remember the solution someday, please post it :)

Comment: ok sorry that didn't work for you :( if I remember what I had to do other than changing that line I will post it .. unless someone else chimes in with the solution first ... I cant remember if I had to change the mounting point in some way to get it to work but as I say on my system that is the line I use and I can create files and delete files from the drive .. even tho it says root:root as the owner.. permissions on the folder are 777 though

Comment: That solved it, the folders permission was 755 and not 777. I thought I already changed it, but I guess I deleted this one at some point. Anyways thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When mounting a NTFS drive using fstab you need to create the mount point and change permissions on the folder to 777 ..then add a line in your fstab like the following example:

```
UUID=<the drives uuid number> /path-to-mounting-point ntfs-3g defaults 0 0

UUID=F858A91658A8D522 /media/mountpoint ntfs-3g defaults 0 0
```

You can find the UUID by running `sudo blkid`